# Why flush a CharsetDecoder?

Tags: java, character-encoding, flush

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) for `CharsetDecoder` says

> A decoder should always be used by making the following sequence of method invocations, hereinafter referred to as a decoding operation:
>
> 1. Reset the decoder via the reset method, unless it has not been used before;
> 2. Invoke the decode method zero or more times, as long as additional input may be available, passing false for the endOfInput argument and filling the input buffer and flushing the output buffer between invocations;
> 3. Invoke the decode method one final time, passing true for the endOfInput argument; and then
> 4. Invoke the flush method so that the decoder can flush any internal state to the output buffer.

It seems like #3 and #4 are doing the same thing: indicating that there is no more input, so the decoder can finish up.

If I do both, I'm not sure what my error-handling logic should look like.

What is the difference between these two operations, and why are both necessary?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between these two operations?

- #3 finishes decoding and handles malformed input, and sets the decoder's internal state to "end".
- #4 calls the abstract method `implFlush()` (default behavior does nothing) and sets the decoder's internal state to "flushed" if it was already "end", otherwise throws an exception if not already "end".

> and why are both necessary?

They're both necessary to account for all possible CharsetDecoder implementations. Specifically, to give concrete subclasses clear separation between decoding, handling of malformed input, and flushing buffered resources.

> If I do both, I'm not sure what my error-handling logic should look like.

The API is designed to fail at #4 in any case when #3 wasn't called successfully. And there's generally no point in invoking #3 after a prior failure of #2. Therefore, you need not have any local error-handling logic (try..finally blocks) for your CharsetDecoder; merely call the methods one after the other in the recommended sequence.

Comment: I handle overflow errors. if I understand you correctly, if I don't get an overflow on #3 I shouldn't get an overflow on #4? (Since, if I did, the decoder would be ended anyway.)

Comment: @PaulDraper that is correct, if you don't get an overflow on #3 you shouldn't get an overflow on #4

Answer (score 0):

Since `CharsetDecoder` is an abstract class, it's anyone's guess how that design choice came to be. Arguably it could have been designed with #3 also handling the flushing (by delegating to `implFlush()`), instead of relying on the caller to do it.

Also note that #4 is a NOOP, if the decoder doesn't keep any internal state.